# JAVA the method GetConnection() is undefined for the type C

Tags: java

this is a java program designed to simulate a connection pool
but the compiler says the method GetConnection() is undefined for the type C
how to deal with it ...
I'm new in Java..
do you have other advice for my connection pool? Or what else implementation  can I add?

```
package hello;

public class C {

public  static void  main(String[] args) {
 CConnection con=new CConnection();
 con=GetConnection();
 System.out.println(con.pos);
 }

 public static class CConnectionManager {
  private static final int MaxConSize=10;
  private CConnection[] connections ;
  {
  connections=new CConnection[MaxConSize];
  }


  public CConnection GetConnection(){
   for(int i=0;i<connections.length;i++){
    if(1==connections[i].status){
     continue;
    }
    else if(0==connections[i].status){
   connections[i].status=1;
   connections[i].pos=i;
   return connections[i];
   }
  }

  System.out.println("No connection available,Please wait");
   return null;
 }


  public void CloseConnection (CConnection con){

  if(-1==con.pos||0==con.pos){
      System.out.println("No such connection");
  }
  else
      connections[con.pos].status=0;
  }
}



 public static class CConnection  {
  private int status=0;
  public int pos=-1;
  public void execute(String sql){

  System.out.println(sql);
  }

}

}
```

Comment: Method names should be lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should try to add as much information as possible to your questions. In this case it might have been good to actually paste the error message you got. The problem you have is quite basic, and looking into how to instantiate and use object from your `main()` method might be a way forward for you.

Comment: but how can I fix it? How can I call GetConnection() with a CConnect object?...there is no friend class in Java.

Answer (score 2):

`GetConnection()` is an instance method of your inner `CConnectionManager` class.
You can only call it on an instance of that class.

Comment: but how can I fix it?  How can I call GetConnection() with a CConnect object?...there is no friend class in Java..

Comment: @WangShuo: What? Just create an instance of the class.

Comment: I mean.. my original idea is that I want to create a CConnect object con, and use GetConnection to initialize con.. Can it be?

Comment: @WangShuo: Yes; it is possible to call a funciton.  You need to learn the basics of Java and classes.

Comment: since it's possible.. how can I use object con to call GetConnection? Could you show me an example?